# How can I change how many spaces emacs indents the first line of an anonymous function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, emacs

I think that emacs is counting the number of opening parenthesis/brackets, and indenting 4 spaces for each.  So my code is indented like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Hello');
    }, 1000);
```

Instead of this, which I prefer:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Hello');
}, 1000);
```

How can I change this?

EDIT:  M-x version gives me:  GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.3) of 2010-03-26 on crested, modified by Debian

I'm not able to update my emacs version, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24915776/354577) I suspect that you are using `java-mode`. As recommended in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24917555/354577), it is a good idea to use a dedicated JavaScript mode like `js-mode`, `js2-mode` or `js3-mode` to edit JavaScript code.

Both `js-mode` and `js2-mode` indent your sample code the way you want:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Hello');
}, 1000);
```