# How can I stop emacs from indenting the 2nd line of a javascript comma-separated list (e.g. array or json)?

Tags: javascript, emacs

Emacs indents my code like this:

```
var myArray = [
    1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
    ];
```

Instead of like this:

```
var myArray = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
];
```

How can I prevent this?

M-x version gives me:  GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.3) of 2010-03-26 on crested, modified by Debian

I'm not able to update my emacs version, unfortunately.

Comment: Too bad you can't update Emacs, version 24 is pretty nice :-). Which major mode are you using? (Try `C-h m` to see a list of active modes.)

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could update.  I'll look into it but last time I checked, I was told it was not an option.  Here's the major (and minor) mode output.  I'm editing a file with a .js extension.    Enabled minor modes: Abbrev Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Auto-Fill Column-Number File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock
Global-Auto-Composition Global-Font-Lock Line-Number Menu-Bar
Shell-Dirtrack Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Java/l mode:
Major mode for editing Java code.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to upgrade the Emacs package. You should be able to drop a binary version (or build from source) in your home directory and run out of `~/bin/emacs` or something.

Comment: Did you have any luck installing a dedicated JavaScript mode?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using `java-mode` to edit JavaScript code. While Java and JavaScript share enough syntax that this will probably work okay, it is better to use a dedicated JavaScript mode¹.

Emacs [includes `js-mode` from version 23.2](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JavaScriptMode#toc1), which is a reasonably good mode for basic JavaScript editing. If you can upgrade Emacs this is likely your easiest option. You may also be able to install `js-mode` (or its predecessor `espresso-mode`) on Emacs 23.1. Here is the [latest version](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/js.el?h=emacs-24).

Alternatively, you can use a third-party mode like [`js2-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Js2Mode), which actually includes a full JavaScript interpreter. There is also [`js3-mode`](https://github.com/thomblake/js3-mode), which claims to be

> A chimeric fork of js2-mode and js-mode

Both `js2-mode` and the version of `js-mode` built into my Emacs 24.4 indent your sample code exactly as you want:

```js
var myArray = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
];
```

¹Unfortunately, there is still enough confusion out there that it's worth stating that Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. You probably already know this; I think Emacs actually defaulted to `java-mode` for JavaScript code for a while.